# C# Passing struct as parameter

Tags: c#, struct, parameters

I have the following code in C#:

```
public class ELL
{
    public struct RVector
    {
        private int ndim;
        private double[] vector;

        public RVector(double[] vector) => (ndim, this.vector) = (vector.Length, vector);
        public double this[int i] { get => vector[i];  set => vector[i] = value; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string str = "(";

            for (int i = 0; i < ndim - 1; i++)
                str += vector[i].ToString() + ", ";

            str += vector[ndim - 1].ToString() + ")";
            return str;
        }
    }
    private static void SwapVectorEntries(RVector b, int m, int n)
    {
        double temp = b[m];
        b[m] = b[n];
        b[n] = temp;
    }
    public static void M(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new double[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        var b = new RVector(a);

        Console.WriteLine(b);
        SwapVectorEntries(b, 1, 2); // Why after this command, b will be changed?
        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
}
```

In this program, i creates a struct `RVector`. After that, i use a method `SwapVectorEntries` which have a struct parameter. Because, Struct is a `value type`, so i think the method  `SwapVectorEntries` will not change the struct parameter. But, in the program, after the command `SwapVectorEntries(b, 1, 2);`, b has changed. Please explain me about this. Thank you !

Comment: You are not modifying the structure, you are modifying the array.  Arrays are not value types.  Declaring a structure with a mutable reference type as a field is not a great idea.

Comment: Also, you can skip vector values initialization (in `public RVector(int ndim)` constructor): in c#, every item of the new created array will have it's default value (0.0, in your case using double). That's different from C/C++

Comment: You can also avoid having a `ndim` member variable: you can replace it with `vector.length` every time you need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is in this.You have an array wich is `reference type`.When you create your

```
double[] a = new double[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
RVector b = new RVector(a);
```

you have two references to that array.After when you pass your object into the method,

```
SwapVectorEntries(b, 1, 2);
```

your object is copied,**BUT** your new object have the **same reference** to that array.Here your have only one array and **many references to it.**

[image]

Comment: But, `b` is an instance of structure `RVector`. It 's created by using a constructor with an array-parameter. So, i think `b` is a value type.

Comment: Yes b is a value type.But when it copies as parameter,all it's fields also copies,and beacuse "double[] vector" is a reference,it's value(the address of the array) also copies .So you are having 2 different objects of RVector,but they have to vectors which refer to the same object.

Comment: Your answer is very clear. Now I has understood it. Thank you very much  !

Answer (score 2):

B itself is not passed as a reference, but the copy of b has a Reference to the same `double[]`.